# How can I achieve a collapsing header with tab layout in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, swiftui-tabview

I want to create something similar as in the gif attached is shown but then in SwiftUI (and also not buggy scrolling this is due to the gif). My screen contains a horizontal paging scrollview with inside of that multiple vertical scrollViews in which my content is placed.

already offset is working with a custom scrollview and my initial thought was to check scrolling direction with dragGesture. (but this will not work if you drag up and down it won't detect the gesture.

[image]

```
struct ScrollingHeaderView: View {

@State var progress: CGFloat = .zero
@State var offset: CGPoint = .zero
@State var previousOffset: CGPoint = .zero

@GestureState private var dragGestureActive: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.black
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHStack(spacing: .zero) {
                // ForEach looping through an array of contents
                OffsetObservingScrollView(axes: .vertical, offset: $offset) {
                    // My scrolling content
                }
                .onChange(
                    of: self.offset,
                    perform: { value in

                        let scrollY = value.y

                        let distance = scrollY - previousOffset.y
                        self.previousOffset = value

                        let progress = distance / 30
                        let scrollProgress = min(max(progress, 0), 1)
                        self.progress = scrollProgress
                    }
                )
                .simultaneousGesture(
                    DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                        .updating($dragGestureActive) {
                            value, state, transaction in
                            state = true
                        }
                        .onChanged { value in
                            let direction = 0 < value.translation.height ? .down : .up
                        }

                )
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: Where does an actor named OffsetObservingScrollView come from?

Comment: @ElTomato this is a custom component which uses a preference key to track scroll view offset